# Redirection page for all my external links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, external-links

I have a wordpress affiliate website. I need a build a middle page for all my external links. I'm using 'redirection' plugin for the redirections. To better understanding, in a new tab that page must be show up for 2 seconds then the external link will open.

Page>Redirection page(2 sec)>external page

I tried to handle it with plugins but js is what i need it

Comment: I will explain to see if I understand correctly.

Do you want all external links to go to a fixed page when they are clicked, to wait 2 seconds there (show ads or count seconds) and then be directed to an external page?

Comment: yes it's correct

Answer (score 0):

according to your case, In my opinion, the fastest way to achieve this goal is to use a plugin.
Using the Mihdan `plugin: No External Links`
To redirect to a specific page in WordPress or similar plugins.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mihdan-no-external-links/

Comment: i didn't find anything about the redirection page in that plugin, as far as i see, this is a plugin for all external link's convert into internal plugin. Do you have any other suggestions?